# Eclipse Plugin Development: Get Active WorkBench bounds

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to create an eclipse plugin in which I need to get the bounds of the active workbench that I am getting with:

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow()
```

I am able to get the shell bounds by

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getShell().getBounds()
```

but I need to get the bounds of the textEditor with respect to the display
i.e. The Starting pixel location of the textEditor w.r.t. the OS Display like I get in the

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getShell().getBounds()
```

Comment: Why? This is an unusual thing to want. It is straightforward for code in the editor but outside of the editor I'm not sure that there is a way.

Comment: @greg-449 I need this for some project of mine. Some tests that I want to run specifically on the current working document in eclipse workbench

Also, can you elaborate on what do you mean by "It is straightforward for code in the editor" ?
Maybe that can solve the problem I am facing right now

Comment: In an editor `createPartControl` method you just call `toDisplay` on the main `Composite`.